# Sample Input from file

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to create the input for rules from a sample file. The sample file contains a Column SampleID which should be used as sample wildcard. I want to extract the paths of normal and tumor bams from the columns Path_Normal and Path_Tumor per SampleID from the data frame.

For this I tried like this:

```
import pandas as pd

input_table = "sampletable.tsv"

samples = pd.read_table(input_table).set_index("SampleID", drop=False)

rule all:
      input:
        expand("/directory/sm_mutect2_paired/vcf/{sample}.mt2.vcf", sample=samples.index)

rule Mutect2:
    input:
        tumor = samples[samples['SampleID']=="{sample}"]['Path_Tumor'],
        normal = samples[samples['SampleID']=="{sample}"]['Path_Normal']
output:
        "/directory/sm_mutect2_paired/vcf/{sample}.mt2.vcf"
    conda:
        "envs/gatk_mutect2_paired.yaml"
    shell:
        "gatk --java-options '-Xmx16G -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16' Mutect2 \
            -R /directory/ref/genomics-public-data/references/hg38/v0/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta \
            {input.tumor} \
            {input.normal} \
            -L /directory/GATK_interval_files_Agilent/S07604514_hs_hg38/S07604514_Covered.bed \
            -O {output} \
            --af-of-alleles-not-in-resource 2.5e-06 \
            --germline-resource /directory/GATK_gnomad/af-only-gnomad.hg38.vcf.gz \
            -pon /home/zyto/unger/GATK_PoN/1000g_pon.hg38.vcf.gz"
...
```

When doing a dry run I do not get an error message but the execution fails because the input is empty which becomes looking at the log:

```
atk --java-options '-Xmx16G -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16' Mutect2             -R /directory/GATK_ref/genomics-public-data/references/hg38/v0/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta                                       -L /directory/GATK_interval_files_Agilent/S07604514_hs_hg38/S07604514_Covered.bed             -O /directory/WES_Rezidiv_HNSCC_Clonality/sm_mutect2_paired/vcf/HL05_Rez_HL05_NG.mt2.vcf             --af-of-alleles-not-in-resource 2.5e-06             --germline-resource /directory/GATK_gnomad/af-only-gnomad.hg38.vcf.gz -pon /directory/GATK_PoN/1000g_pon.hg38.vcf.gz
```

The two input files should appear between "Mutect2" and "-R".

So it looks I am doing something wrong defining the inputs...

Answer (score 0):

You need to defer the determination of the input files of that rule to the so-called DAG phase, when jobs and wildcard values are known. This works via [input functions](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#functions-as-input-files). I would strongly recommend to do the [official Snakemake tutorial](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/tutorial.html), which covers this topic in depth.